# C# - Thread start blocks current thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Previously, I ran a method in a thread like this:

```
static void procedure() { while (x) thread.sleep() }
static Thread runner;

...

void method(){
    runner = new Thread(new ThreadStart(procedure));
    runner.Start();
}
```

I changed this in an attempt to have a single thread that I can start at different points.

```
static void procedure() { while (x) thread.sleep() }
static Thread runner;

void main(){
    runner = new Thread(new ThreadStart(procedure));
    ...
}
...

void method(){
    runner.Start();
}
```

This no longer runs the thread as expected. The program halts, which I believe is due to the new thread running on the main thread.

Why is it no longer running on a seperate thread?

Comment: What is your evidence that it is not running in a separate thread? I don't see why moving where you initialize the field should change anything.

Comment: How do you expect us to debug your code without a [short self contained correct example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Also, are you sure this is C#? The framework looks more java'y than .net.

Comment: What about this code isn't C#? What about this is even *java'y*?

Comment: The only thing I could see happening with this change is that if you called `method` twice in the first case you'd get two threads. In the second case, you'd get one thread and an exception thrown saying you tried to start a thread that was already running. Are you ignoring an exception somewhere?

Comment: Yep; I found I was calling `Start()` twice, which I've since stopped doing. No exception was being thrown, though.

Comment: Also, I ended up using a flag for the while loop to pause/resume the thread, instead of using start/stop/resume etc.

Comment: @Aron Side note on sscce - [MCVE] is more commonly used on SO for the same purpose as it also includes links to more guidance. And it only 6 characters to type in comment "[ M C V E ]".

Comment: @Tobiq The camel case vs pascal case. The framework doesn't look like .net.

Comment: It's a matter of my preference... I will say, I forgot to capitalise the `.Sleep` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine, here's an example based on your code.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void procedure()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Sleep");
            }
        }
        static Thread runner;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            runner = new Thread(new ThreadStart(procedure));
            Console.WriteLine("Here!");
            runner.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("And now here...");

        }
    }
```